# How can we use partition in Oracle query

Tags: oracle

I have query in which i used partition of avoid the duplicate value for particular column , but still it is giving duplicate row below i am mention my query in which i used partition

```
SELECT iol.M_product_id  as faultyProduct ,  iol.SERIALNO,iol.M_product_id as newproduct, ma.Description,
                    mp.M_Product_category_id ,mi.issotrx, co.C_BPartner_ID,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ma.Description ORDER BY iol.M_product_id DESC) rn
                FROM M_inoutline iol

                inner join M_inout mi ON (iol.m_inout_id = mi.m_inout_id)
                inner join C_Order co ON (co.c_order_id = mi.c_order_id )
                inner Join M_AttributeSetInstance ma ON (ma.m_attributesetinstance_id =iol.m_attributesetinstance_id)
                inner join M_Product mp ON (mp.m_product_id = iol.m_product_id)
            where   mp.m_product_category_id= 1000447 AND mi.issotrx = 'Y';
```

Please help me out

Comment: For which particular columns you like to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it looks you want to do:

```
select * from (/*YOUR QUERY*/) where rn = 1;
```